# OpenLayers: get Map, View, TileLayer and OSM from server

Tags: javascript, html, css, thymeleaf, openlayers

I am new using OpenLayers (an open-source JavaScript library for displaying map data in web browsers as slippy maps). I am using it with Thymeleaf (a Java XML/XHTML/HTML5 template engine that can work both in web and non-web environments).

I am trying to reproduce this example, but getting the resources from the server https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-wgs84.html

I have this page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css">

    <style>
        .map {
            width: 100%;
            height:400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="layout">


    <div id="main">

        <div class="content">
            <div class="pure-g">

                <div class="pure-u-1-1 pure-u-xl-10-24 pure-u-med-1">

                    <!-- Content right Wrap -->
                    <div class="content_r_wrap">

                        <!-- Devices Map Module -->
                        <div class="windowHead">
                            <h2>LOCATION INFO</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="windowContentMap">
                            <div id="map" class="map"></div>
                                <script th:inline="javascript" th:type="module">
                                  /*<![CDATA[*/
                                  import Map from '/css/Map';
                                  import View from '/css/View';
                                  import TileLayer from '/css/layer/Tile';
                                  import OSM from '/css/source/OSM';

                                  var map = new Map({
                                    layers: [
                                      new TileLayer({
                                        source: new OSM()
                                      })
                                    ],
                                    target: 'map',
                                    view: new View({
                                      projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                                      center: [0, 0],
                                      zoom: 2
                                    })
                                  });
                                  /*]]>*/
                                </script>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and I would like to know how to get those objects also from the server:

```
  import Map from '/css/Map';
  import View from '/css/View';
  import TileLayer from '/css/layer/Tile';
  import OSM from '/css/source/OSM';
```

Comment: What's the exact issue? If I start you code as a simple HTML it works just fine. The only thing I can imagine is that the paths to the modules you want to import are wrong. By the way `css` is a really bad name for a folder with `js` in it.

Comment: Maybe you don't know how to add static resources to Thymeleaf? Then maybe this will help: https://memorynotfound.com/adding-static-resources-css-javascript-images-thymeleaf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what mean but if "getting from the server" means accessing the imports directly from a compiled source (be it on your server or elsewhere), this is how to do it:

```js
const Map = window.ol.Map;
const View = window.ol.View;
const TileLayer = window.ol.layer.Tile;
const OSM = window.ol.source.OSM;

var map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>


       <style>
         .map {
           width: 100%;
           height: 400px;
         }

       </style>


       <div id="layout">


         <div id="main">

           <div class="content">
             <div class="pure-g">

               <div class="pure-u-1-1 pure-u-xl-10-24 pure-u-med-1">

                 <!-- Content right Wrap -->
                 <div class="content_r_wrap">

                   <!-- Devices Map Module -->
                   <div class="windowHead">
                     <h2>LOCATION INFO</h2>
                   </div>
                   <div class="windowContentMap">
                     <div id="map" class="map"></div>
                   </div>
                 </div>

               </div>

             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
```

you actually get the built file from `CDN` (I guess, "the server" you talked about).
So, in that file you can access the modules `Map, View, TileLayer, OSM` etc... All as a result of the import of the script from `CDN`.

If you want to load these files from your local project, which can be "offline", you can install them using Package Manager (like [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol)) or just download the bundled (built) files (`css` and `js`), save them in a directory you could access to, and change your source to the directory.

My recommendation (and also OpenLayer's) is using `npm` and then use it regularly (import `ol`):

**index.js**

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
  })
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Using Parcel with OpenLayers</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 400px;
        height: 250px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In that case, OpenLayer's files are INSTALLED in your project inside node_modules and you are no longer dependent on external network traffic to the `CDN`.

That's it :)

You can follow the complete guide here (they explain there how to bundle and run the program):

[OpenLayers using NPM](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html)